# Display Image From Database in .rdlc report

Tags: rdlc

I have one simple report in which I display company information.

In my sql database I have a CompanyMaster table in which i have one column **Company Logo**. In that column I only store the path of the company logo image.

Now i want to display company logo in report with company information,

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Image control in rdlc file. Common approach is to write an Webservice that returns the Image content. So your Image URL will point to web service URL.

You webserivce class needs to inherit ImageHandler as follows:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ServeImage" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Web;
using MyControllers;

public class ServeImage : ImageHandler {

    public ServeImage()
    {
    }

    public override ImageInfo GenerateImage(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
        ImageInfo retVal = null;

        if (parameters["ID"] != null)
        {
            MyController myCntl = new MyController();
            // myCntl.GetImageFromDB returns the binary[] content from database
            retVal = new ImageInfo(myCntl.GetImageFromDB(parameters["ID"]));
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. I think, I should be sorry for making you click on to an another page. Time for steps.

1.) EnableExternaImages= true for your sample report.

2.) Insert an image in your Report. Set the image source as external.

3.) Enter the expression in "use this image".

4.) Enter the value of your image file link that is saved in Database eg . of such expression is : "file:/// " + First(Fields!Imagelink.Value, "DataSet1") + ".jpeg"

5.) Important thing is that your Imagelink value must be the complete path to that image.

## Note use "file:///" before the link.

6.) Any more issue please comeback and ask again. :-)

Comment: I hope this may help miss Kleopatra

Answer (score 0):

1- Create Text Parameter

2- Add Image Control to the Report

3- Set the Image to be External external and set "Use this image" to be the 
parameter: [@ParameterName].

4- Finally Set the Parameter Value in Code behind before loading the report.

[Setting image source in RDLC report dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454972/setting-image-source-in-rdlc-report-dynamically)