# Html Image in rdlc is not working

Tags: c#, rdlc

i am using a html content to generate rdlc report. I have already set the placeholder properties set to html. 
All the other html tags are interpreted correctly. but the html image tag is not being rendered in rdlc report. it shows nothing (blank space) instead of image in rdlc report.
Does rdlc support html image tags or not?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `img` tag is not supported.

The only way to add an image to rdlc report is by using the `Image Control`.
Don't forget to set the property on `External`.

I'll also share this post here to help you add images dynamically as it is a great example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722377/4579864