# blazor html image tag convert to pdf

Tags: base64, blazor, rdlc

I'm using blazor c# and i can generate PDF using RDLC, I have this html code with data in it using database and i want to add that image into RDLC
Example code below.

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" src="@data.QRCodeBase64" title="@data.tbl_req_document_header.qr_code" />
```

Comment: Take a look here and try to make your question better [ask]

Comment: This has already been answered in SO before, `<img>` tag is not supported. But there are still ways to embed image in RDLC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722377/6670491

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.