# RDLC report does not display uploaded images

Tags: c#, file-upload, rdlc

I have an RDLC report that I'm putting out as a PDF download. The report is based on a bunch of user-inputted data included some image uploads. I can take the images and store them just fine, but when it comes to displaying these images in the report, all that is displayed is the red X of 'no image found'. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454972/setting-image-source-in-rdlc-report-dynamically) is in the same vein, but following that solution did not help.

What I'm doing is saving the image to disk and writing details to a DB entry. Things like file name, path to where it was saved, file type, etc. I pull that info when the PDF is generated and pass the file path as a report parameter to the RDLC where that report parameter is used in the Image control in the report. The image is set as External and the parameter set for "use this image".

There is error logging in this project but since the error happens during report generation, the logging doesn't catch it. The only indication I have other than the red X on the PDF is the line "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll" during report generation. I've tried both External and Database image sources in the image control. I've tried both URL reference and passing in a byte array of the image data to try and get the image to display. I know the report parameters are working fine because I have another simple text parameter that displays correctly.

How can I get user-submitted images to display in my RDLC report?

I've tried hard-coding the image URL to at least simulate an uploaded image. I've tried submitting a byte array. I've found several sources dealing with displaying images in RDLC reports but none of them have given me a working solution.

Comment: There are three different places where errors can occur 1) The c# code in an exception handler 2) The Report Server Log files than can be found in the start button under Microsoft Report Server 3) The SQL database errors that can be found using SQL Server Management Studio using the explorer under Management.

Comment: @jdweng The error is happening somewhere in the System.Drawing DLL. The error displays in the Visual Studio Output window after clicking the PDF generate button. I don't understand how SQL could throw an error here. I even put a try/catch around the Render function of the report viewer to see what it would catch and all it got was the thread abort because of ending the response.

Comment: the most likely reason is the query is not returning any results and then when you try to draw the null results you are getting an exception.  Check the log files like I said.  The SQL query should be in the log files.  Then check in SSMS if the query returns results.

Comment: @jdweng I know the SQL side is good because I can see in the C# that the data object gets filled. The error is in the report generation. Additionally, I deleted the error log location just to make sure the server is forced to generate a new log. When I ran the report with the expected image failure, no log file popped up.

Comment: The RDLC is HTML format.  The SQL Query is in a tag Command_Text and you should be able to run the command in SSMS except that you may need to modify the special escaped characters like `&`.  The images are probably URI paths and the paths may not be found.  You can check by opening the RDLC file with notepad and checking the URI locations.

Comment: @jdweng I don't know how I can make this any more clearer. There is no SQL in the RDLC. That data is being pulled in C# code and being populated by passing as a report data object. If you want, the way that is described in the XML is `<CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>`

Comment: Your RDLC is HTML format and to display images it would be exactly the same as adding images to any webpage.